# What styles did Google use for their new Gmail toolbar?

Tags: javascript, css, layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Swap CSS class on the basis of Scroll Position with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548765/swap-css-class-on-the-basis-of-scroll-position-with-javascript)

So if go into themes and select Preview you can see the new layout to gmail.  It has a tool bar that has your archive,spam,delete,move to, etc.. buttons.  It starts in a static location under the search mail section, but once you almost scroll past it, it remains directly at the top of your page.  (and vice versa)

I have done the div remaining at the top of your page before, but not the part where it starts at a static location, scrolls like any other part, then once you scroll almost past it, it remains at the top.

Any idea how this was done?

Comment: @Matt Ball can you give a link the same specific question in that case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swap CSS class on the basis of Scroll Position with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548765/swap-css-class-on-the-basis-of-scroll-position-with-javascript) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396133/element-floats-according-to-scroll and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593245/holding-scroll-position-of-a-div-tag-as-page-refreshes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249557/using-a-simple-jquery-script-to-have-a-div-follow-the-page-on-scroll

Comment: @Matt Ball thanks, two of the four were what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use JavaScript to determine when the element is at the top of the page as the page is scrolled.  When it is, apply a class to it that makes it fixed position.

There's a tutorial on it @ http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you just give the element `position:fixed` using javascript when the page is scrolled past a certain point.  Why don't you just inspect the element using firebug or another browser's developer tools?